# How to use redirect at listview on django

Tags: django

I want to use redirect at listview on django.

If username is yusl, he connect to [www.example.com/user/yusl](http://www.example.com/user/yusl), he can see his photo list, and if he connect to [www.example.com/user/dksdl](http://www.example.com/user/dksdl), it makes him to redirect [www.example.com/user/yusl](http://www.example.com/user/yusl).

but there are error. error is

```
TypeError at /user/user/
context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://ec2-13-124-23-182.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/user/user/
Django Version: 1.11.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect.
Exception Location: /home/ubuntu/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/context.py in make_context, line 287
Python Executable:  /home/ubuntu/my_env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/project',
 '/home/ubuntu/my_env/lib/python35.zip',
 '/home/ubuntu/my_env/lib/python3.5',
 '/home/ubuntu/my_env/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/ubuntu/my_env/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/ubuntu/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 4 Jun 2017 17:41:21 +0000
```

this is my views.py

```
class PhotoListView(ListView):
    model = Photo

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        User = get_user_model()
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

        if not user == self.request.user:
            return redirect('index')

        context = super(PhotoListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['photo_list'] = user.photo_set.order_by('-posted_on','-pk')
        return context
```

this is urls.py

```
url(r'^user/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$', PhotoListView.as_view(), name='photo-list'),
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't return a redirect from `get_context_data`, because as the name implies, that's for getting a template context.

Instead you need to do it from the method that actually creates and returns the response; in this case, the `get` method.

Also note, your code is unnecessarily complicated: all it needs to do is to check if the user has the required authorization to access the view, there is no need to query the database at all.

So:

```
class PhotoListView(ListView):
    model = Photo

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('index')
        return super(PhotoListView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```